# Get GPS coordinates without onLocatioChanged() method

Tags: java, android, location

I am creating an app that writes GPS coordinates in a file every one second. Is there any way I can get GPS coordinates without using onlocationchanged().

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, there is no way you can find GPS co-ordinates every second even when you are using onLocationChanged callback methods. getLastKnownLocation() or read up on FusedLocationProvider  as that might be of some help to you.

Comment: What about Pending Intents ?